# How to get the highest and the lowest points in the hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
@participants[id] = {nick: nick, points: 1}
=>  {"1"=>{:nick=>"Test", :points=>3}, "30"=>{:nick=>"AnotherTest", :points=>5}, "20"=>{:nick=>"Newtest", :points=>3}}
```

I want my the lowest points `(ID: 1 and 20)`. How do I get the lowest points go first and then ID 30 go last?

Comment: The first line makes no sense in the context of the question and the second is unindented and out of a code block. You should show the input value and the output value you want (not explain it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Enumerable#max_by()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) or [Enumerable#min_by()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) you can do following;

```
data = {
 "1"  => {nick: "U1", points: 3}, 
 "30" => {nick: "U30", points: 5}, 
 "20" => {nick: "U20", points: 3}
}

max_id, max_data = data.max_by {|k,v| v[:points]}

puts max_id # => 30
puts max_data # => {nick: "U30", points: 5}
```

Same thing works with [#min_by()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) and if you want to get back [Hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) you do this:

```
minimal = Hash[*data.min_by {|k,v| v[:points]}]
puts minimal # => {"1"=>{:nick=>"U1", :points=>3}}
```

Functions [min_by()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) and [max_by()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) will always return **one record**. If you want to get all records with same points then you have to use min / max data an do another "lookup" like this:

```
min_id, min_data = data.min_by {|k,v| v[:points]}
all_minimal = data.select {|k,v| v[:points] == min_data[:points]}

puts all_minimal
# => {"1"=>{:nick=>"U1", :points=>3}, "20"=>{:nick=>"U20", :points=>3}}
```

Comment: There's also [`Enumerable#minmax_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) to get the min and max in a single pass through the enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are not a suitable data structure for this operation. They are meant when you need to get a value in `O(1)` complexity.

You are better off using a sorted array or a tree if you are interested in comparisons or Heap (in case you are interested in only maximum or minimum value) as @Vadim suggested

Comment: Heap is the best if you just want to know the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable#minmax_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by):

```
h = { "1"=>{:nick=>"Test", :points=>3},
     "30"=>{:nick=>"AnotherTest", :points=>5},
     "20"=>{:nick=>"Newtest", :points=>3}}

h.minmax_by { |_,g| g[:points] }
  #=> [[ "1", {:nick=>"Test", :points=>3}],
  #    ["30", {:nick=>"AnotherTest", :points=>5}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the fact that `min_by` and `max_by` are returning only one result by combining `sort` and `chunk`:

```
data.sort_by{|_,v| v[:points]}.chunk{|(_,v)| v[:points]}.first.last.map(&:first)
#=> ["1", "20"]
```